# unexpeced output after initializing a NumericMatrix class member in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

On adjusting `a` of type `NumericMatrix` of class `myclass` (invoked using `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS`) using `myclass::fill_values`, I seem to be affecting the other member `b`, that inexplicably takes on the same value as that of `a`.

The Rcpp code is:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp ;

class myclass{
    public:
        NumericMatrix a;
        NumericMatrix b;

        void init(const int&, const int&);
        void fill_values(const int&, const int&, const double&);
};

void myclass::init(const int& nrow, const int& ncol){

    NumericMatrix numeric_zeros(nrow,ncol);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nrow ; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol ; ++j){
            numeric_zeros(i,j) = 0.0;
        }
    }
    a = numeric_zeros;
    b = numeric_zeros;
}

void myclass::fill_values(const int& nrow, const int& ncol, const double& value){

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nrow ; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < ncol ; ++j){
            a(i,j) = value;
        }
    }
}

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(myclass)

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix simple(const int& nrow, const int& ncol, const double& value){
    myclass mymember;
    mymember.init(nrow,ncol);
    mymember.fill_values(nrow,ncol,value);
    return(mymember.b);
}
```

The `R` output is:

```
> simple(2,2,15.0)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   15
[2,]   15   15
>
```

I suspect that the error stems from my initialisation function `myclass::init` but I haven't been able to make much headway finding the bug.

What's wrong with my code, and can someone advise the best way of initialising `NumericMatrix/Vector` class members?

Comment: It just struck me that one "solution" is replacing `b = numeric_zeros` with `b = Rcpp::clone(numeric_zeros)`. I am not certain if this is the way to go however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, but I can suggest a couple of changes:

1. Get rid of your `init` member function - `NumericMatrix` objects are initialized with `0`s by default, so there's no need to loop through each element and do this yourself. Even ignoring the loop, you can spare yourself the creation of intermediate objects (not just `numeric_zeros`) by initializing `a` and `b` directly in a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). This is generally recommended for non-integral data types (`NumericMatrix`, for example).
2. As far as your example is concerned, you can get rid of the `fill_values` method and just implement its functionality in your own constructor (rather than using the compiler generated one).

Here's a possible implementation that takes the above points into account:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class myclass2 {
public:

  myclass2(int nrow_, int ncol_, double value_ = 0.0) 
  : a(nrow_, ncol_), b(nrow_, ncol_)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow_; i++) {
      a(i, Rcpp::_) = Rcpp::NumericVector(ncol_, value_);
    }
  }

  Rcpp::NumericMatrix a;
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix b;
};

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(myclass2)

// [[Rcpp::export("simplea2")]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix simplea(int nrow, int ncol, double value){
  myclass2 mymember(nrow, ncol, value);
  return(mymember.a);
}

// [[Rcpp::export("simpleb2")]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix simpleb( int nrow, int ncol, double value){
  myclass2 mymember(nrow, ncol, value);
  return(mymember.b);
}
```

---

In the `myclass2` source file I defined `simplea2` and `simpleb2` (which return the data members `a` and `b`, respectively); and did the same for the source file that contains your original definition of `myclass`, i.e.

```
/* 
 * Class definition from your question...
 */

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix simplea(const int nrow, const int ncol, const double value){
  myclass mymember;
  mymember.init(nrow,ncol);
  mymember.fill_values(nrow,ncol,value);
  return(mymember.a);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix simpleb(const int nrow, const int ncol, const double value){
  myclass mymember;
  mymember.init(nrow,ncol);
  mymember.fill_values(nrow,ncol,value);
  return(mymember.b);
}
```

---

Comparing these two classes,

```
R> simplea(2,2,15.0)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   15
[2,]   15   15
R> simpleb(2,2,15.0)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   15
[2,]   15   15
##
R> simplea2(2,2,15.0)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   15
[2,]   15   15
R> simpleb2(2,2,15.0)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
```

you can see that `b` is no longer affected by the changes made to `a`.